# Is there an official map of Hyperion?

Tags: hyperion-cantos

If not an official map, are there any accurate representations or approximantions of Hyperion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reddit user [/u/endwigast](https://www.reddit.com/user/endwigast) created their own version of Hyperion maps, namely for Equus and Aquila. The thread with the maps can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Hyperion/comments/nz2hxz/i_made_hyperion_maps_equus_and_aquila/).